# Regex anything but not contain

Tags: regex

Here is the original text:

```
<p><u><font face="Calibri">2013<u>Blablabla</u><u></u></p>
<p><u>Blablabla</u><u></u></p><p>
```

I want to use the follow regex

```
<p><u>(.*?)<u>(.*?)</u><u></u></p>
```

to replace the redundant `<u>` in the first line

```
<p><u><font face="Calibri">2013<u>Blablabla</u><u></u></p>
```

However, this regex also include the second line which is no problem!

Please help, thanks!

Comment: is it problem or not???

Comment: What would your expected output and which language are you running?

Comment: i am using PHP and would like to replace the redundant <u> in the first line. As it will make all the text remain in underline format because it does not close yet.

Answer (score 0):

With all the warnings about using regex to parse htlm, you can use this:

```
(?s)<u>(?=(?:(?!</u>).)*?<u>)
```

See the match in [the demo](http://regex101.com/r/fQ1iD5/40).

**Explanation**

- `(?s)` activates `DOTALL` mode, allowing the dot to match across lines, in case the second `<u>` was on another line
- `<u>` matches our desired `<u>`
- The lookahead `(?=(?:(?!</u>).)*?<u>)` asserts that what follows is...
- `(?:(?!</u>).)` one character that is not followed by `</u>`,
- `*?` as many times as necessary, up to
- the second `<u>`